# Mapping Container<T> to T using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

My question is very similar to the one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40287029/automapper-generic-conversion), but I was unable to find a solution based on the provided answers. I must be missing something that's right around the corner.

I have a custom converter that allows me to do the following:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Container<int>, int>().ConvertUsing(new ContainerConverter<Container<int>, int>());
```

But `int` being not the only type argument, is there a concise way to express:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Container<T>, T>().ConvertUsing(new ContainerConverter<Container<T>, T>());
```

Without having to do:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Container<int>, int>().ConvertUsing(new ContainerConverter<Container<int>, int>());
cfg.CreateMap<Container<long>, long>().ConvertUsing(new ContainerConverter<Container<long>, long>());
...
```

For every `T` in use?

In my situation, properties of `Container<T>` and `T` are in turn members of classes `A1, A2...` and `B1, B2...`. The mapping is performed by calling

```
B dest = mapper.Map<A, B>(source);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Open-Generics.html

Comment: @jalsh I will once I give the solution a try. Thanks.

Comment: @Lucian Bargaoanu Hi Lucian, can you explain how I can specify the destination type systematically?

Comment: You can use object. If you don't want that, you can use a [simple object mapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/c755b9d905e34d91c1544321988dd036c195980d/src/UnitTests/Mappers/CustomMapperTests.cs#L70).

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I have a custom converter declared as: `public class ContainerConverter : ITypeConverter<object, object>`. And in the mapper configuration I have: `MapperConfiguration config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { ... cfg.CreateMap(typeof(Container<>), typeof(object)).ConvertUsing(new ContainerConverter()); )})`.

For me, this works if Container is a class, but my Container is a struct. The new MapperConfiguration() call raises a System.ArgumentException saying that Container cannot be used for parameter of type object. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you don't mind the boxing, you can use a generic converter.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap(typeof(Container<>), typeof(object)).ConvertUsing(typeof(ContainerConverter<>));
    });
    config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    //config.BuildExecutionPlan(typeof(Destination), typeof(Source)).ToReadableString().Dump();
    var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    mapper.Map<int>(new Container<int>{ Value = 12 }).Dump();
}
public class ContainerConverter<T> : ITypeConverter<Container<T>, object>
{
    public object Convert(Container<T> source, object destination, ResolutionContext c)
    {
        return source.Value;
    }
}
public class Container<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```